# Incomprehensible work decorator function

Tags: javascript

Is a function:

```
var f = function(a) { console.log(a) };

function throttle(func, ms) {
    var stop = false, savedThis, savedArgs;

    return function wrapper() {
        if(stop) {
            savedArgs = arguments;
            savedThis = this;
            return;
        } 

        func.apply(this, arguments)
        stop = true;

        setTimeout(function() {
            stop = false;
            if(savedArgs) {
                wrapper.apply(savedThis, savedArgs);
                savedArgs = savedThis = null;
            }
        }, ms);
    };
}

// brake function to once every 1000 ms
var f1000 = throttle(f, 1000);

f1000(1); // print 1
f1000(2); // (brakes, less than 1000ms)
f1000(3); // (brakes, less than 1000ms)
```

The first call `f1000 (1)` displays 1. `f1000 (2)`, the second call does not work, but it will keep in `savedAggs` link to the arguments of the second call. The third launch also does not work, but it will overwrite the link to the arguments of the third call. Through 1000 ms `setTimeout` cause an anonymous function, the variable will `stop` within the meaning of the `false`. Condition of work, and the `wrapper` will be called recursively. But then I can not understand what's going on? When this code works: `savedArgs = savedThis = null;`?

Comment: did you tried debugging?

Comment: @JordiCastilla, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is a bit incomprehensible, yes. Its job is to throttle the rate of invocations to at most one per 1000 ms - however if they occur more frequent, it will also repeat the last invocation as soon as the timeout has finished.

It might better be written

```
function throttle(func, ms) {
    var stop = false, savedThis, savedArgs;
    function invoke() {
        stop = true; // the last invocation will have been less than `ms` ago
        func.apply(savedThis, savedArgs);
        savedThis = savedArgs = null;
        setTimeout(function() {
            stop = false; // the timeout is over, start accepting new invocations
            if (savedArgs) // there has been at least one invocation during
                           // the current timeout
                invoke();  // let's repeat that
        }, ms);
    }
    return function wrapper() {
        savedArgs = arguments;
        savedThis = this;

        if (stop)
            return;
        else
            invoke();
    };
}
```

Comment: I know what the function does. I just do not understand what happens when the wrapper calls itself recursively. When this code works: savedArgs = savedThis = null;?

Comment: That line just resets the `savedArgs` so that they won't be used again after `wrapper()` has called `func` with them. This doesn't really get clear in the original function. If they weren't reset, the timeout would always believe that there had been an extra invocation in the last period, and keep repeating those calls forever.

Comment: When the wrapper invokes itself, inside the function is called f, and outputs 1. Changes variable stop = three. Then again setTimeout works or does this line: savedArgs = savedThis = null; ?

Comment: Yes, after having called the `func` it will set `stop=true` and schedule a new timeout. Then it returns from the `wrapper.apply(savedThis, savedArgs)` call and resets the `savedArgs` (and `savedThis`) which were still laying around. When the scheduled timeout expires, (and no other invocation of `wrapper()` has happened in between), only `stop` will be set to `false` and no new cycle would start.

Comment: That is, when the first fire setTimeout simultaneously called wraper and zeroed savedArgs and savedThis?

Comment: Yes (though technically, there is no "simultaneous" in js)

Comment: I mean, when triggered the first setTimeout, it runs wrapper.apply (savedThis, savedArgs); Then in the wrapper called func.apply (this, arguments) and the variable stop = three, the next step planned new timeout, but in the old call setTimeout triggered this line: savedArgs = savedThis = null, and then the next start condition is not setTimeout triggered if (savedArgs). Right?